# SQL Server 2008 Instance Install Path

Tags: sql-server

We currently have 2 named instances of SQL Server 2008 installed and the folder paths for the database engine look like this

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.DevSQL.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.StagingSQL

I'm now trying to install a 3rd named instance, I give it the instance name of TestSQL during the install but for some reason it installs to this path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.10

I would really rather the folder naming convention followed our first 2 installs so it installed to MSSQL.10.TestSQL

Is there something I need to do in the installer to get it to install the database engine in this path

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the instance root directory to point to the desired directory in the Instance Configuration step of the install wizard.

I thought that the install wizard did this automatically when installing a named instance so are you sure that you're installing a named instance rather than a default instance?